# How to upload massive number of books automatically to database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I have a client who has 130k books (~4 terabyte) and he wants a site to upload them into it and make an online library. So, how can I make it possible for him to upload them automatically or at least upload multiple books per time? I'll be using Node.js + mysql

Comment: Sure. Maybe? What do you mean "upload?" As in to what? Why not just clone the drive, put it in a server and call it done? Services like Amazon can ingest external drives and dump them on their S3 service, for example.

Comment: Furthermore, would you be uploading the entire content of the books, or just putting the names and covers in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest using Object Storage on top of MySQL to speed up book indexing and retrieval- but that is entirely up to you.

HTTP is a streaming protocol, and node, interestingly, has streams.

This means that, when you send a HTTP request to a node server, internally, node handles it as a *stream*. This means, theoretically, you can upload massive books to your web server while only having a fraction of it in memory at a time.

The first thing is- book can be very large. In order to efficiently process them, we must process the metadata (name, author, etc) and content seperately.

One example, using an express-like framework, could be: **pseudo-code**

```js
app.post('/begin/:bookid', (Req, Res) => {
    ParseJSON(Req)
    MySQL.addColumn(Req.params.bookid,Req.body.name,Req.body.author)
})

app.put('/upload/:bookid', (Req, Res) => {
   //  If we use MySQL to store the books:
   MySQL.addColumn(Req.params.bookid,Req.body)
   //  Or if we use object storage:
   let Uploader = new StorageUploader(Req.params.bookid)
   Req.pipe(Uploader)
})
```

If you need inspiration, look at how [WeTransfer](https://developers.wetransfer.com/documentation/#create-a-new-transfer) has created their API. They deal with lots of data daily- their solution might be helpful to you.

Remember- your client likely won't want to use Postman to upload their books. Build a simple website for them in Svelte or React.